# How can I access a variable outside of define in requirejs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I have the following module implemented based on `ko` (knockout).

```
define(['ko'],
    function(ko) {
        function compareViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.products = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.addProduct = function(p) {
                self.products.push(p);
            }
            self.visible = ko.computed(function() {
                return self.products().length > 0;
            });
        }

        return { cvm: compareViewModel() };
    });
```

I want to be able to access `cvm` outside of `define`

```
$(function () {
    //ACCESS CVM HERE    
    $('.compare-chk').click(function () {
        var $chk = $(this).prev('input:checkbox');
        if ($chk !== 'undefined') {
            if (!$chk.is(':checked')) {
                cvm.addProduct($chk.attr('value'));
                console.log(cvm.products());
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order you access `cvm` you have to state that you need the module where this is defined:

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'ko'], function($, ko){
    $(function () {
    //ACCESS CVM HERE    
        $('.compare-chk').click(function () {
            var $chk = $(this).prev('input:checkbox');
            if ($chk !== 'undefined') {
                if (!$chk.is(':checked')) {
                    ko.cvm.addProduct($chk.attr('value'));
                    console.log(ko.cvm.products());
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Note** It's quite possible that the modules and libraries in the array we pass as the first argument of `requirejs` need some tweaking. You have to specify where these files are in your application. For instance, please have a look [here](https://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/07/requirejs-amd-tutorial-introduction/), which is an introductory tutorial in requirejs or [here](http://requirejs.org/), which is the official documentation of the library.

Comment: @AliKhakpouri You are welcome. I am glad that I helped.